# Воспроизведение звука 1 раз в таймере

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

День добрый. Подскажите, как поправить или закостылить таймер, который вызывает функцию (`ajax`) и та в случае успешного ответа проигрывает звук..нужно чтобы звук проигрался ровно 1 раз, а не повторялся с течением таймера

```
            success: function(data) {
             var audio = new Audio('https://САЙТ.ru/assets/files/accept.mp3');
            audio.play();
              if (audio !== undefined) {
                audio.then(_ => {

                })
                .catch(error => {

                });
                }
                },
```

Comment: *в случае успешного ответа* - интересует только первый успешный ответ, а остальные молча? сделайте переменную до объявления функции, по значению которой будете решать воспроизводить или нет

Comment: Да..только первый успешный ответ..остальные должны пролетать беззвучно..Допустим я сделаю переменную и дам ей 0. В момент успешного ответа я даю ей значение 1 и играю звук..и он будет все равно вечно проигрываться. Или я не правильно понял ?

Comment: `let played; $.ajax({..., success: function (data) { if (!played) { played = true; audio.play(); } ...}, ...}); `

Comment: @yar85 не выходит..Консоль начинает плеваться ошибками и спустя 30 дублированных ошибок звук начинает циклично играть. Ошибка - `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`

Comment: Может медиа-объекты не разрушаются... Вынеси строку `var audio = new Audio(...);` за пределы `$.ajax` - в самое начало скрипта.

Comment: Никогда не стартируйте воспроизведение аудио следующей строчкой после его объявления - не успевает инициализироваться. От сюда и 30 одинаковых ошибок, так как такое-то время требуется, чтобы браузер прочитал содержимое аудиофайла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const audio = new Audio('https://webaudioapi.com/samples/audio-tag/chrono.mp3');
  let played; 
  $('button').click(function () {
    const $btn = $(this); 
    $.ajax('https://httpbin.org/robots.txt', {
      success: function(data) {
        if (!played) {
          played = true; 
          audio.play();
        }
        $btn.text(+$btn.text() + 1); 
      }
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

```css
button { padding: 0.5em 0.8em; font: 20px sans-serif; }
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Длительность музыки в примере - 57 секунд (первая страница гугла не дала ничего покороче).
Значение счетчика на кнопке увеличивается только чтобы показать успешное выполнение каждого запроса.

Comment: Вроде вышло, но при обновлении страницы в консоль те же ошибки идут..но это не критично. Спасибо

Comment: @CryEngineV-FlowGraph, ошибки по какой-то внешней причине - ведь в сниппете консоль чистая, проблема не повторяется.